# Electron require is not defined in renderer process

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm starting with electron and for some unknown reason I can't use require() function in renderer process.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at index.js:1
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-electron-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "author": "your name",
  "description": "My Electron app",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^12.0.2"
  }
}
```

**main.js**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const ipc = ipcMain;

function createWindow () {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntergration: true, 
      contextIsolation: false,
      devTools: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

  win.loadFile('index.html')
  
    win.webContents.openDevTools()

  ipc.on("closeApp", ()=>{
    console.log("clicked on Close btn")
    win.close();
  })
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()

  app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow()
    }
  })
})

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body style="background: white;">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <p>
        We are using Node.js <span id="node-version"></span>,
        Chromium <span id="chrome-version"></span>,
        and Electron <span id="electron-version"></span>.
    </p>
    <button id="closeBtn">close</button>
    
    <script defer src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
const ipc = ipcRenderer;

var closeBtn = document.getElementById('closeBtn');

closeBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    ipc.send("closeApp");
});
```

[Screenshot of my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvmDW.png)

I am doing everything like in the tutorial, I have searched for solution for two days and tried everything, nothing works. I am worried that only I have that problem :v

Comment: I think that's because `nodeIntegration` is disabled. Maybe the tutorial is old.

Comment: weird. This would typically happen if either node was disabled or context isolation was enabled, but it looks like you're enabling/disabling them correctly. Are you sure that the code you posted matches exactly what you have?

Comment: Yes, I've checked 3 times. Should I reinstall node.js?

Answer (score 2):

There's a typo in `nodeIntegration` (you spelled it `nodeIntergration`). That's probably the problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to get the ipcRenderer from the preload.js script and then expose it to the environment using a contextBridge.

```js
//preload.js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("myappvar",{
  close:()=>ipcRenderer.invoke("closeApp"),
});
```

then after this, in your main you can create an ipcMain to handle the closeApp call, and also anywhere else in your app you can reference the function using `myappvar.close()` or `window.myappvar.close()`

An example of main:

```js
// main.js
const { app, ipcMain } = require('electron')


/* omitted some code stuff before */

ipcMain.handle('closeApp',()=>{
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit();
})

/* More stuff after */
```

Also lastly, as another user @bubs16458 has pointed out [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67044430/18263070), try fixing your typo from *`nodeIntergration`* to **`nodeIntegration`**

---

Try these and see if it all works out for you! Nice day!

---